# Lipschitz continuity of a minimum of a set of linear functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request, continuity

I have a multidimensional function $A(h, u)$, that is linear in $u$ for any $h$, and convex in $h$. How can I prove that $\mathcal{A}(u) = \min_h A(h, u)$ is Lipschitz? If this is some standard theorem, then I would be grateful for textbook reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. For example, $A(h,u)=hu$ (both $h,u$ in $\mathbb R$) satisfies the conditions, but taking the infimum over $h$ results in discontinuous function 
$$\mathcal {A}(u) = \begin{cases} 0 ,\quad & u=0\\ -\infty, \quad & u\ne 0\end{cases}$$

Here is what can be said:

1. $\mathcal{A}$ is a concave function of $u$ (standard fact: concavity is preserved by taking infimum of a family of functions).
2. A concave function on $\mathbb R^n$ is locally Lipschitz on the set where it is finite (i.e., not equal to $-\infty$). (See, e.g., [A convex function that is bounded on a neighborhood is Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/419123). A standard reference is *Convex Analysis* by Rockafellar.)

So, if in your case $\mathcal{A}$ never turns into $-\infty$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is  *locally* Lipschitz.

You don't get global Lipschitz continuity without  extra assumptions. Example: if $A(h,u) =  hu+h^2$ (again,  both $h,u$ are in $\mathbb R$), then the minimum is attained at $h=-u/2$, and therefore $\mathcal A(u) = -u^2/4$.